# Calling PyTorch Estimator Hyperparameter in Training Script in SageMaker

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

In [PyTorch Estimator for SageMaker][1], it says as below.

> hyperparameters (dict) – Hyperparameters that will be used for
> training (default: None). The hyperparameters are made accessible as a
> dict[str, str] to the training code on SageMaker. For convenience,
> this accepts other types for keys and values, but str() will be called
> to convert them before training.

```
estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='test_trainer.py',
                   source_dir = 'code',
                    role = role,
                   framework_version = '1.5.0',
                   py_version = 'py3',
                   instance_count = 1,
                   instance_type = 'ml.g4dn.2xlarge',
                   hyperparameters={"epochs": 1,
                                     "num_labels": 2,
                                     "backend": "gloo"
                         }}
```

So, should I declare my estimator as above and fit the estimator via my test_trainer.py, I should be able to access these values of hyperparameter within my test_trainer.py. But how exactly should I call this hyperparmeter in order to access these hyperparam values ?

Any resource would be greatly appreciated.
[1]: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SM_HPS='{"batch-size": "256", "learning-rate": "0.0001","communicator": "pure_nccl"}'
Contains a JSON encoded dictionary with the user provided hyperparameters. Example usage:

import os
import json

hyperparameters = json.loads(os.environ['SM_HPS']))
# {"batch-size": 256, "learning-rate": 0.0001, "communicator": "pure_nccl"}
```

[AWS Document](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-containers#sm_hp_hyperparameter_name)